# com.microsoft.appcenter.crashes.Crashes.saveUncaughtException

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, visual-studio-app-center

I'm getting a crash report in AppCenter with the below error:

```
com.microsoft.appcenter.crashes.Crashes.saveUncaughtException
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack trace available
```

There is no reference to our code at all, I can see in our settings of the Android device the average memory being used is 19MB while the devicesRAM is 2.7GB.

The only details we are getting back are:

```
Version Code: 3
Version Name: 3.6.2
Android: 7.1.1
Android Build: 84.00.17
Manufacturer: Honeywell
Model: CT60
CrashReporter Key: bf010497-95e7-4486-8794-54914647c815
Start Date: 2020-03-09T15:30:58.752Z
Date: 2020-03-09T16:35:33.523Z

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: OutOfMemoryError thrown while trying to throw OutOfMemoryError; no stack trace available

Thread 86:
0   java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-2)
1   java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:150)
2   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

Thread 87:
0   java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-2)
1   java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:407)
2   java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:188)
3   java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:209)
4   java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:204)
5   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

Thread 88:
0   java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:-2)
1   java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:371)
2   java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:313)
3   java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.sleepFor(Daemons.java:314)
4   java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.waitForFinalization(Daemons.java:336)
5   java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:253)
6   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

Thread 89:
0   dalvik.system.VMRuntime.runHeapTasks(VMRuntime.java:-2)
1   java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.run(Daemons.java:433)
2   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

Thread 95:
0   dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(VMStack.java:-2)
1   java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1566)
2   java.lang.Thread.getAllStackTraces(Thread.java:1616)
3   com.microsoft.appcenter.crashes.Crashes.saveUncaughtException(Crashes.java:970)
4   com.microsoft.appcenter.crashes.Crashes.saveUncaughtException(Crashes.java:935)
5   com.microsoft.appcenter.crashes.UncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(UncaughtExceptionHandler.java:20)
6   java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1068)
7   java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:1063)

Thread 97:
0   java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:-2)
1   java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2127)
2   sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
3   java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:161)
4   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2035)
5   java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
6   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1058)
7   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
8   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
9   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)

Thread 98:
0   android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java:-2)
1   android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
2   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
3   android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Has anyone has issues like this?

Answer (score 0):

The VM's heap size for the application process is limited to 16 or 24MB (depending on the device). It can be 36 or even 48MB, but only if you're using "largeHeap" setting.

So I think it's quite possible your app has some memory leak. 
If you are sure you need more memory allocated to your app, you can add `android:largeHeap="true"` to the app's manifest. This is not recommended though, as it might slow other running applications as well as yours.

For more info see [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/tips-for-optimizing-android-application-memory-usage).